# Automatically flush() changes on a GWT Editor

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I'm looking into implementing a way to bind an object/DTO to fields in a view. I found the GWT Editor and implemented that, and it looks like it might work alright, but don't like that you have to call flush() manually.

Is there a way to have it automatically update the DTO I gave it when the user changes some field? Or do I need to plan to call flush() whenever I'm ready to do some sort of data processing/saving?

Thanks!

Comment: You can find some suggestions for data binding here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396786/best-data-binding-solution-for-gwt

Comment: Thanks Simon. I read that article. It was what turned me on to using the Editor in the first place. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Unless you want to bind the ChangeEvents on every widget in your form, I don't think there's a viable data binding solution at the moment other than the Editors. So yes, you'll have to flush your POJOs manually.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was afraid of.